# Git : Do not allow users to push a new branch to remote repo

Tags: git, git-push, remote-branch

Sometimes by mistake some of users tend to push their local branches to a remote repo creating a new branch on the remote repo. How can we disallow the users to create new branches on a remote repo but still allow them to push changes to the existing ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just have them remove the branch when they push it by mistake?

Comment: Yeah this is what we have been doing. But it would be good to know if there is someway we can disallow it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends a bit on where your remote repository is. If you have full control over it, creating an `update` [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) would probably be the easiest solution. You would just check the branch name (ref name) with a list of allowed branches, and if it does not match, reject the update.

If you are using [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) for access control to your repository, you can also just specify the [rules](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rules.html) to apply only to known branches and disallow push access to all others.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah adding a hook looks like a possible solution. Sorry forgot to mention we are using gitorious to host our repo and could not easily find the access control setting on it.

Comment: @SmitShah Unfortunately it is not possible to set such things in Gitorious directly. If you are hosting Gitorious yourself, you can add custom hooks though. See the sample file `/data/hooks/custom-update.sample` for more information.